# javascript window.close() works in one case but doesnt in another

Tags: javascript, html

in both the cases , i am trying to close a popup window opened from the same parent using the similar code. In both cases the function is being called inside the call back function of the jquery $.post method. But while  one of them works properly, the other one throws an error

Firefox:

> > window.close is not a function

Chrome:

> > Property 'close' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

I tried to do this separately with two simple html files having minimal code .. and it works perfectly

this is the code i am using to open the popups

```
<a onclick="window.open('<?php echo $personalize_href; ?>',null,'height=688,width=1000,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=2,location=no');">
```

Please help

Comment: Can you show the code you used to open the window? Are both URLs on the same domain?

Comment: yes trying to do it .. could some one tell me how to post javascript code here

Comment: Just post it and mark it using the "code" button (the one with the 00101010)

Comment: And your question is confusing. Where are you when you are trying to close the window? In the window? In the parent?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `self` instead of `window`.

`self` references the current window, whereas `window` references the parent window.

`self` is actually a `DOMWindow` object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a handle to the window (or reclaim a handle to the window...)

```
var myWin = window.open(uri, "myWin", "height=300, width=200");

...

myWin.close();
```

Comment: +1, this is the other way to go as opposed to making calls from within the new window.

Comment: thanks but this is not working either .. 
error 
<pre>myWin is not defined</pre>

Answer (score 0):

thanks Pekka..

this is how i am calling window.open

```
<a onclick="window.open('<?php echo $personalize_href; ?>',null,'height=688,width=1000,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=2,location=no');" class="button">
```

by two different cases what i meant was, there is a parent window with two links which open two different popups .. one gets closed using window.close, the other doesnt
and i am calling the window.close function from the popup windows in both the cases.. along with some other code 
which is this

```
window.close();
        if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
        window.opener.location.href = 'xyz';
        }
```